# when i run migration command using (laravel 5.7) this happend, How to solve?

Tags: laravel, migration

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/id8zS.png)

(Note: I've added these two lines on 'AppServiceProvider.php' file:
     use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
     and 
     schema::defaultStringLength(191);
)

Comment: Paste your code here. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this command:

```
composer update
```

Comment: unfortunately not works, these two lines comes with red marks

# Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

# Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of these methods to resolve this issue.

1. Paste the following command in your terminal

   composer require jakub-onderka/php-console-highlighter
2. If the above doesn't work for you then delete your vendor folder and run the following command.

   composer install

Comment: unfortunately not works, these two lines comes with red marks

# Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

# Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

Comment: Hmm, Try this. 
Remove your vendor folder and then run.
composer install --ignore-platform-reqs

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
composer dump-autoload
```